# Why cannot we use outer joins in Recursive CTE?

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

Consider the below

```
;WITH GetParentOfChild AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Rn = ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By (Select 1))
            ,row_id AS Parents
            ,parent_account_id  As ParentId 
        FROM siebelextract..account
        WHERE row_id = @ChildId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Rn + 1
            ,a.row_id as Parents
            ,a.parent_account_id As ParentId    
        FROM siebelextract..account a
        JOIN GetParentOfChild gp on a.row_id = gp.ParentId
    )

SELECT TOP 1 @ChildId = Parents 
FROM GetParentOfChild
ORDER BY Rn DESC
```

What it does is that given any child , it will return the root level parent....The program is perfectly working fine all the time...

Just out of curiosity/experimental sake i changed the JOIN to Left Outer Join and it reported

**Msg 462, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetParent, Line 9
Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'GetParentOfChild'.**

My question is why recursive part of CTE cannot accept Left Outer Join? Is it by design?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is by design, read [Guidelines for Defining and Using Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

> The following items are *not allowed* in the CTE_query_definition of a
>   recursive member:
>
> - SELECT DISTINCT
> - GROUP BY
> - HAVING
> - Scalar aggregation
> - TOP
> - LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER JOIN (INNER JOIN is allowed)
> - Subqueries

Notice that if your query make a left join to it self through CTE can become to an infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't think this answer or the link actually answers "why".  I wanted to coalesce two left joins (to external tables) to control the direction of the next iteration for example.  Infinite recursion doesn't seem like a good reason to abandon all while loops.

Comment: @crokusek, prepare your coalesce query in a previous cte expresion and inner join it into your recursive cte query.

Comment: Ha, I tried it and it runs, neat trick.  If i did it right, I had to convert the left joins to full outer in the cte.  It ran but the query plan becomes miserable--it computes the full outer completely before starting on the rte (wouldn't finish, depending on sizes), losing the niceness of recursively probing only exactly what it needed.  A cursor would out perform except when the cte result is small.  Probably a nice workaround for some cases nonetheless.

Comment: "Infinite recursion" can occur *anyway* .. and *since* such a CTE will terminate with 100 recursive levels, "can become to an infinite recursion" is not a good justification to give.

Answer (score 34):

You can't use LEFT JOIN with recursive CTE but you can use OUTER APPLY which should give the same results.

So...

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table tb2 on tb1.Prop = tb2.Prop
```

becomes...

```
OUTER APPLY (select * from table tb2 where tb1.Prop = tb2.Prop) tb2
```

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: I'm wondering WHY this is allowed, as it is conceptually the same thing...

Comment: I've never heard of "OUTER APPLY", so an example of how to replace a LEFT JOIN with an OUTER APPLY would have been nice.

Comment: @Michael `LEFT OUTER JOIN table tb2 on tb1.Prop = tb2.Prop` becomes `OUTER APPLY (select * from table tb2 where tb1.Prop = tb2.Prop) tb2`

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to define a foundational CTE with de LEFT OUTER JOINS, and then use it as a table in your recursive CTE:

```
WITH 
InitialQuery as (
    -- here de left outer joins


),

GetParentOfChild AS
(
        FROM InitialQuery 
)

SELECT TOP 1 @ChildId = Parents 
FROM GetParentOfChild
ORDER BY Rn DESC
```