# Create recursive query in Snowflake with a Left Join condition?

Tags: sql, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I am trying to create a recursive query that relies on a `LEFT JOIN` condition, but I am not sure if it is possible, especially in Snowflake.

I have three tables: `ITEM`, `ITEMHIERARCHY`, and `ITEMVALUE`

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM
(
  NAME STRING
);

INSERT INTO ITEM(NAME)
VALUES
('Item1'),('Item2'),('Item3'),('Item4'),('Item5'),('Item6');

CREATE TABLE ITEMHIERARCHY
(
 ITEM STRING,
 SUBITEM STRING 
);

INSERT INTO ITEMHIERARCHY(ITEM,SUBITEM)
VALUES
('Item2','Item3'),('Item2','Item4'),('Item4','Item5'),('Item6','Item4');

CREATE TABLE ITEMVALUE
(
  ITEM STRING,
  VALUE NUMERIC(25,10)
);

INSERT INTO ITEMVALUE(ITEM,VALUE)
VALUES
('Item1',34.2),('Item3',40.5),('Item5',20.3),('Item6',77.7);
```

My goal is to return a list of all `ITEMs` with values and sub-item values rolled-up:

```
Item1, 34.2
Item2, 60.8 //roll-up of Item3 + Item4
Item3, 40.5
Item4, 20.3 //roll-up of Item5
Item5, 20.3
Item6, 77.7 //since Item6 value is given, dont roll-up from Item4
```

Note that even though `Item6` is a roll-up from `Item4` because there is already a given value of `77.7` on the `ITEMVALUE` table, the roll-up is ignored.

Here is my attempt at a failing recursive query due to the `LEFT JOIN` in the `UNION ALL` clause:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ITEMHIERARCHYFULL
  -- Column names for the "view"/CTE
  (ITEM,SUBITEM,VALUE) 
AS
  -- Common Table Expression
  (

    -- Anchor Clause
    SELECT it.NAME ITEM, ih.SUBITEM, iv.VALUE
      FROM ITEM it
      --These left-joins work
      LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv ON iv.ITEM = it.NAME 
      LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY ih ON ih.ITEM = it.ITEM
                                 AND iv.VALUE IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Clause
    SELECT  ihf.ITEM, ih.SUBITEM,  
      IFF(ihf.VALUE IS NOT NULL,ihf.VALUE,iv.VALUE)
      FROM ITEMHIERARCHYFULL ihf
      LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv ON iv.ITEM = ihf.SUBITEM
      LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY ih ON ih.ITEM = ihf.SUBITEM
                                    AND iv.VALUE IS NULL 
  )

 -- This is the "main select".
 SELECT ITEM, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
 FROM ITEMHIERARCHYFULL
 GROUP BY ITEM
 ORDER BY ITEM
 ;
```

The goal of the query is to first get all top level `ITEMs` from the `ITEM` table, search for a corresponding value on the `ITEMVALUE` table, and, if none is found, join to the `ITEMHIERARCHY` Table to retrieve all `SUBITEMs` that compose the top level `ITEMs`. I would then like to recursively search on the `ITEMVALUE` table for a `SUBITEM-VALUE` match, or, if none is found, retrieve the `SUBITEMs` from the `ITEMHIERARCHY` table.

The first set of `LEFT-JOINs` work, but not the ones under the `UNION ALL` giving me the error:

```
SQL compilation error: OUTER JOINs with a self reference are not allowed in a recursive CTE.
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do in `Snowflake` or am I not thinking about this correctly?

Currently I manually wrote out the recursive layers to 5 levels meaning I have to add a level if the `ITEMHIERARCHY` table becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example that gives you the results you expected. You can also view it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2b4b/3).

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT 
        i.NAME
        , IH.SUBITEM AS descendant        
        , CASE WHEN IV.VALUE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LEVEL
    FROM ITEM AS i
    LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY AS IH
        ON i.NAME = IH.ITEM
    LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE AS IV
        ON I.NAME = IV.ITEM
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CTE.NAME
        , sIH.SUBITEM
        , 1 AS LEVEL
    FROM CTE
      INNER JOIN ITEM AS si
        ON CTE.descendant = si.NAME
      INNER JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY AS sIH
        ON si.NAME = sIH.ITEM
  ), CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT 
    CTE.NAME     
    , LEVEL
    , SUM(IV.VALUE) AS VALUE
    , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CTE.NAME ORDER BY CTE.LEVEL ASC) AS RNK    
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE AS IV
    ON (CTE.LEVEL=0 AND CTE.NAME = IV.ITEM)
    OR (CTE.LEVEL <> 0 AND CTE.descendant = IV.ITEM)    
GROUP BY CTE.NAME, CTE.LEVEL
) 
SELECT 
    NAME
    , VALUE
FROM CTE2
WHERE RNK = 1
ORDER BY 
    NAME
;
```

RESULTS:

```
NAME    VALUE
Item1   34.2000000000
Item2   60.8000000000
Item3   40.5000000000
Item4   20.3000000000
Item5   20.3000000000
Item6   77.7000000000
```

Comment: I added in another use case, `Item6`, to demonstrate why this query won't work for my purposes. If a higher level Item is given on the `ITEMVALUE` table, then I want that value and not a roll-up of the lower levels. That is why the `LEFT-JOIN` is necessary.

Comment: @EliSquared I updated the query to meet your new requirements. It is pretty complex I must admit, and there could probably be some code cleanup if needed.

Comment: Ill mark yours as the correct answer since technically it does do what I would like it to do, but I tried running on Snowflake on a very small data table of 20 rows and it took more than 1 minute to execute. Looks like I will just have to use manual recursive layers, which from my testing appear to execute much more quickly. Fortunately since it is unlikely my data will have more than 5 or 6 levels, it should be manageable. I really wish they would just allow `LEFT JOINs` in the recursive clause and put in a recursion limit to prevent `∞ recursion`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stack overflow question about why `LEFT JOINs` are not allowed in recursive queries: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126704/why-cannot-we-use-outer-joins-in-recursive-cte), basically it is to prevent `∞ recursion`, which is a little bit of a weak reason imo. It is also suggested on the second response that if your SQL dialect supports `OUTER APPLY` you can use that instead for functional equivalence, but Snowflake does not have that function.

Here is my manual "recursive" solution for up to 3 levels of hierarchy:

```
SELECT rec.ITEM, 
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN rec.VALUE1 IS NOT NULL THEN rec.VALUE1
    WHEN rec.VALUE2 IS NOT NULL THEN rec.VALUE2
    ELSE rec.VALUE3
  END) VALUE

FROM (
  SELECT it.NAME ITEM, 
  ih1.SUBITEM SUBITEM1, CASE 
                         WHEN iv1.VALUE IS NOT NULL THEN iv1.Value
                         ELSE iv1s.Value 
                        END Value1,
  ih2.SUBITEM SUBITEM2, CASE 
                         WHEN iv2.VALUE IS NOT NULL THEN iv2.Value
                         ELSE iv2s.Value 
                        END Value2,
  ih3.SUBITEM SUBITEM3, CASE 
                         WHEN iv3.VALUE IS NOT NULL THEN iv3.Value
                         ELSE iv3s.Value 
                        END Value3
  
  FROM ITEM it

  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv1 ON iv1.ITEM = it.NAME 
  LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY ih1 ON ih1.ITEM = it.NAME
                             AND iv1.VALUE IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv1s ON iv1s.ITEM = ih1.SUBITEM

  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv2 ON iv2.ITEM = ih1.SUBITEM 
  LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY ih2 ON ih2.ITEM = ih1.SUBITEM
                             AND iv1.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv1s.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv2.VALUE IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv2s ON iv2s.ITEM = ih2.SUBITEM
                             
  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv3 ON iv3.ITEM = ih2.SUBITEM 
  LEFT JOIN ITEMHIERARCHY ih3 ON ih3.ITEM = ih2.SUBITEM
                             AND iv1.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv1s.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv2.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv2s.VALUE IS NULL
                             AND iv3.VALUE IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN ITEMVALUE iv3s ON iv3s.ITEM = ih3.SUBITEM
) rec

WHERE CASE
    WHEN VALUE1 IS NOT NULL THEN VALUE1
    WHEN VALUE2 IS NOT NULL THEN VALUE2
    ELSE VALUE3
  END IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY ITEM
```

This is obviously a syntactically very inefficient approach where on each step you have to check for both `ITEM` AND `SUBITEM` values and then repeat the `NULL` checks on every previous `ITEMVALUE` or `SUBITEMVALUE` table. I put in the `SUBITEMs` for each level so if your run just the inner-part of the query you can see how the expansion works. I also had to use a `CASE` statement to get things working on SQLFIDDLE, but I would have preferred to use `IFF` and
`IFNULL(Value1,IFNULL(Value2,Value3))`.

Here is the working code on SQL Fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28c89/12) and the output:

```
Item1, 34.2
Item2, 60.8
Item3, 40.5
Item4, 20.3
Item5, 20.3
Item6, 77.7
```